# Cheapest place to fly from China, Taiwan, or Southeast Asia to Ishigaki, Japan?

Tags: china, southeast-asia, taiwan, okinawa, ishigaki

I'm pondering meeting up with a friend in Ishigaki, Okinawa, Japan on my upcoming trip.

I'll be on a tight budget hitchhiking from Singapore to China with no real plan or itinerary so any departure airport along that route or even Taiwan would be suitable - if the price is low!

It seems that flight search engines sometimes make it easy to find flights to anywhere in a country, but when I would fly from anywhere in China to one specific airport I can't find any easy way to search.

In fact I don't even know which airlines and routes service Ishigaki but I suppose that will be easier to find.

Comment: I didn't think to check whether the airport in Ishigaki is an international airport. If it's not and this makes the question too silly then I'm fine with closing it. But maybe the answer is still not easy to find an being so close to Taiwan maybe there are direct flights?

Comment: but.. what's the question here?

Comment: @Geeo. Which part don't you understand? I'm looking for a cheap from where to fly to Ishigaki.

Comment: the title!! :-)

Comment: @Geeo: The destination is Ishigaki Japan. The origins include any airport in china, southeast asia, and taiwan.

Answer (score 3):

Well I thought this was going to be a silly question and that Ishigaki's airport might not be international.

But then some hunting revealed that there are in fact direct flights from Taipei to Ishigaki on [TransAsia Airways](https://www.tna.com.tw/en/index.html).

Picking a random date in August I found the price to be $8448.0 `TWD`, which comes to $308 `AUD`, much cheaper than any non-direct flights I have spotted so far.

Answer (score 1):

I've now found another possibility, also from Taipei via the website [momondo.com](http://www.momondo.com/).

[Mandarin Airlines](http://www.mandarin-airlines.com/index.html) seem to have direct flights to Ishigaki for about $295 `AUD` but their website is of such poor quality that I can't work out how to book directly rather than with momondo.